# Not get count update on jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshmonster/kLuff/5/). My count is not update here. Can any one tell me how to solve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    var selected = $('.selected');
    selected.removeClass('selected');
    selected.hide();

    var next = selected.next(".slideritem");
    if(next.length === 0) {
        next = $(".slideritem").first();
    }

    manageControls(next.index());// update the count here
    next.addClass('selected');
    next.show();
});
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kLuff/9/

Answer (score 0):

add

```
$('#CurrenPageId').text(next.index() + 1 + "/" + numberOfSlides);
```

after `next.show()`. Or

```
manageControls(next.index())
```

Here the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLuff/6/

But be aware, that `next.index()` only works, if your slide items are the first items in the container. You may wrap your slide items into another container, so `index()` will be consistent.

Comment: if i want to go prev what should i have to do for that ?

Comment: use `selected.prev()` instead of `.next()`

Comment: is this possible to get the div by click image carousel?

Comment: Sorry, but we shouldn't use the comments here, to develop your project. Please formulate a new and more concrete question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this one: http://jsfiddle.net/karlroos/kLuff/8/